# NetBeans plugin - create process

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

can anybody give me some URLs with documentation about creating process which runs after plugin instalation?

I need it for downloading some data - I want it to do in background - in same way when project is loading; just a progress bar with description in the statusbar of [NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/).

I think I should use [NetBeans Progress API](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.2/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-progress/overview-summary.html) but I couldn't find any examples or tutorials.

Can you help with providing links to documentation or writing some template how to pin time-wasting process to [NetBeans Progress API](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.2/javadoc/org-netbeans-api-progress/overview-summary.html)?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place to start: [Using Progress Bar](http://wiki.netbeans.org/BookNBPlatformCookbookCH0210)